# FB Like and Share button coming in front of fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have a web page which has one fb like and a fb share button. In my page there is a fixed positioned div (black ). Problem is when I scroll down the fb like & share buttons are coming in front of black div. But I want to keep the buttons behind the black div. Please see the web page in this [link](https://needjobbd.000webhostapp.com/jobdetails?id=351)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a z-index applied to your title bar while you have a z-index of 0 applied to the share buttons.

Add a z-index to title bar and you should be good

```
.tb {
    z-index: 1;
}
```